# string de conexión para mongodb con autoscaling en kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

tengo un problema(o duda) con un conjunto de replicas que de mongodb alojadas en kubernetes.

este es mi parte de mi YAML que define el conjunto de replicas:

```
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 5500Mi
              cpu: 400m
            requests:
              memory: 1000Mi
              cpu: 200m
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--bind_ip"
            - 0.0.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 5500Mi
              cpu: 400m
            requests:
              memory: 1000Mi
              cpu: 200m
```

esto crea satisfactoriamente el conjunto tres replicas. adicional a esto el statefulset tiene configurado un HPA(HorizontalPodAutoscaler) para que cree nuevas replicas de ser necesario. Este es parte del YAML del HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-mongo
  namespace: mongo
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: mongo
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
```

esto funciona bien bien. tengo una aplicación en nodejs que se comunica con mongodb, este es el string de conexión :

```
mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017/webhook?replicaSet=rs0
```

ahora el problema. la semana pasada algo ocurrió en el mongo que hizo que el nodo 1 no estuviese disponible, pasando a ser el nodo 2 el primario, lo que hizo que mi aplicación nodejs fallara al escribir en la db. el error:

```
Error en base de datos: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: not primary
```

al revisar las replicas con rs.status() obtengo lo siguiente

```
"members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 873188,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.003Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.002Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 2,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 234599,
                        "configTerm" : 6
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongo-1.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 874678,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.377Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:37.377Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 2,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 234599,
                        "configTerm" : 6
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 878592,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1654271551, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-06-03T15:52:31.595Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1653398324, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T13:18:44Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 234599,
                        "configTerm" : 6,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
```

mi duda es, como puedo hacer para generar un string de conexión dinámico, ya que el statefulset al arrancar lo hace con tres replicas, pero si escala pueden ser mas.

no puedo simplemente agregar al string de conexión:

```
mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-1.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017/webhook?replicaSet=rs0
```

porque estaría abierta la posibilidad de que estos tres en algún momento no estén disponibles y pase a una cuarta replica

estuve indagando y en un foro de mongodb afirmaban que el pasarle el parámetro "replicaSet" al string de conexión se resolvían todos los nombres de los host automaticamente presentes en la replica, pero esto fallo al cambiar el nodo 1 de primaria al nodo 2

Comment: ¿El problema persiste o fue un error temporal? Si el error fue temporal, tal vez se dio durante la elección del nodo primario. Habrá que ver como tienes configurado tu conjunto de réplicas y si estás usando la opción `writeconcern` para las operaciones de escritura. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras el problema pude solventarlo agregando al string de conexión todos los hosts del statefulset

mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-1.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-2.mongo.mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017/webhook?replicaSet=rs0

pero no me parece que sea la mejor solución, indagare sobre el parametro writeconcern que me comentas